# How do I find out if my request was made over HTTP or HTTPS in Play 2.0?

Tags: scala, https, playframework-2.0

How do I find out if my request was made over HTTP or HTTPS in Play 2.0?

Is there a way to find out from the request?

```
def myControllerMethod = Action { request =>
  // this is where I would like to know
}
```

Play 1.X had a solution, it was request.secure. Please let me know if you know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Play! Framework 2.0 doesn't currently support HTTPS (the master branch does seem to have support, but that will probably be rolled into Play 2.1). A great way to deploy Play! (in general, and also to support HTTPS) is to use a front proxy web server, like nginx or lighttpd.

[Here's a guide on setting up a front-end web server](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/HTTPServer). Then, you can just add a special header for HTTPS requests. Additionally, you'll be able to deploy several Play! applications at once, and use the front-end web server to load balance and fail over automatically.

Comment: Since I saw the change was in master for a while, I figured it had made its way into 2.0.3, but I guess not then.  Thanks for the answer.